# Django annotation with reference to another table

Tags: python, django

I have two Django models as follows:

```
class TableA(Model):
    some_string_id: str
    something_i_need: int

class TableB(Model):
    some_string_id: str
```

I am trying to create a `group_by` operation of `some_string_id` of TableA, but also add the `something_i_need` from TableB accordingly. I thought on doing something as follows, but am not sure what to replace the `???` with. Any ideas?

```
TableA.objects.filter(...).values("some_string_id").annotate(something_i_need=???)
```

P.S:
I know that a foreign key could have helped, but those are not my tables to edit...

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: @nigel239, thank you, but in that example they first invoke a DB call to get `newest` and then do another DB call. Isn't there a way to do that in one DB iteration?

Comment: Writing raw SQL will probably do the trick.